# How do I resolve the 'missing xml-layout' error in Android?

Tags: android, android-resources, xml-layout

Whenever i open a new empty activity this shows up.

[image]

I tried syncing with gradle .
I also tried invalidating caches..
I rebuild the project many times but still facing this issue.

Comment: 'missing xml-layout' because of you created a jetpack compose activity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on resource folder and create new directory with layout name and put your xml file in it .